# Senlium IDE not recording Phone number or Zip code in a website form[Soved]

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm a noob when it comes to selenium and I was trying to record Complaint form on a site [https://www.silvercloudfinancial.com/Complaint/] The issue I'm running into is it will record everything except the phone number and zip code fields. I have tried to manually enter ID and Values in IDE and it still didn't work. During playback It leave those fields blank.
I tried to look for similar issue on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything similar. Thanks in advance

Used the Click and sendKey commands and it helped

Answer (score 0):

These fields are doing some additional javascript work on these fields. I was able, in this case, to use a click event followed by send keys to get it to work:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=Phone</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>id=Phone</td>
    <td>5556661234</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phone field is storing in the format of `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` so can you send them by storing in 3 variables. Try with below code, this works for me.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>7890</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>id=Phone</td>
    <td>${x}${y}${z}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try also